# How to make an editable combo box on a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have an MS-Access table setup like this:

```
ID | Name
1  | Place1
2  | Place2
3  | Place3
```

I have a form for the user to edit these names. There is a combo box with a control source to .Name field. The combo box loads the data, but whenever I try to change `Place1` to `Place1NEW` then save or navigate to a new record, it pops up with an error message:

> The text you entered isn't an item in the list.
>
> Select an item from the list, or enter text that matches one of the listed names.

I see that it is giving me this error because I have modified the name and it is looking for a record that doesn't exist, but what do I need to do to get the change to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can automatically add new items on the combobox's `Not in List` event. This will do what you want but has a lot of disadvantages. The biggest being that you basically have no control over what goes into your foreign key anymore. People can add new data willy nilly.
2. You can set the `List Items Edit Form`. When this is set users will see this little icon when the combobox is open.

[image]

If they click it they'll be brought to the (modal) edit form. From there you can control how users add a new item. It also forces people to think if they need a new item or if they can use an existing item. I'd think it also cuts down on "new items" which are just typos of existing items.